# how can i avoid error "can't convert undefined to an object "

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

some of the document does not consists planDetails planId properties and its returning error "can't convert undefined to an object , but i have to fetch that document if these properties exists or not , how can i avoid this error

```
  this.profile.find({ userId: ObjectId(req.id) }).populate("planId").lean().exec(function(err, profileFound) {
  console.log(profileFound);
  if (err) return callback(err);
  if (profileFound && profileFound.length === 0) {
    return callback(false, common.errorMsg("PROFILE DOES NOT EXIST"));
  } else {
    var profileData = profileFound[0];
    profileData["isPlanTaken"] = false;
    profileData["planDetails"] = {};
    if(profileData.hasOwnProperty("planId") && profileData.planId){
      if(Object.keys(profileData.planId).length>0){
     profileData["isPlanTaken"]=true;
      profileData["planDetails"]=profileData.planId;
    }
  }

    return callback(
      false,
      common.successMsg("PROFILE FETCHED",profileData )
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: The error is from `Object.keys()` and it's telling you that `profileData.planId` is `undefined` (or `null`)

Comment: Can you please give me more data for example, because I don't really know what do you need.

Comment: sorry , now check i edited the code

Answer (score 0):

I think there was missing the initialization of profileData  variable only...

```js
const profileData = {};
profileData["isPlanTaken"] = false;

console.log(profileData);

profileData["planDetails"] = {};

if(profileData.hasOwnProperty("planId") && Object.keys(profileData.planId)){
  profileData["isPlanTaken"]=true;
  profileData["planDetails"]=profileData.planId;
}

console.log(profileData);
```

And I think that is also enough to check a property is exists in an object. Can you please give me more data for example, because I don't really know what do you need.

```js
const profileData = {};
profileData.isPlanTaken = false;

console.log(profileData);

profileData.planId = 5; // for example

if (profileData.planId) {
  profileData.isPlanTaken = true;
  profileData.planDetails = profileData.planId;
}

console.log(profileData);
```

Comment: sorry , now check i edited the code

Comment: yes i need to check these fields exists or not if it doesn't exists then i have to ignore this field because some of documents consists planDetail and planId and some documents not so those documents consists these two then it runs normally but if they don't exists it return can't convert undefined to an object